# Rails: controller returns 500 error, not calling model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using this controller to respond to an ajax request, what I am trying to accomplish, is if the user is not logged in, thus the user_id = nil, to not attempt to save the vote and return the "err" partial...But ajax returns a 500 error, can't figure it out. The create method with user_id does work correctly

```
def create
  unless params[:user_id].nil?
    @vote = Vote.new(:song_id => params[:song_id], :user_id => params[:user_id])
    @vote.save
    @song = Song.where(:id => params[:song_id])
    render :partial => "votes/ret", :locals => { :song => @song }, :layout => false, :status => :created
  else 
    render :partial => "votes/err", :layout => false
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have an association in your model?
Than you could solve this much easier.

Best would be if you can tell about association and post the console output of your error.

And you could change

```
unless params[:user_id].nil?
```

to:

```
if params[:user_id]
```

which is doing the same and easier to read.

Bests